# Fixing the format of JSON data for use in google charts api for live graph

Tags: javascript, html, flask, charts, google-api

I am using flask and google charts on a page on my website. I have a page that displays the last row of a database that is in a json object format as such:

```
{"temperature": 11.0, "datetime": "12-12-12 23-23-23"}
```

In flask I am making this getjson page as follows:

```
@app.route('/getjson')
def getjson():
    tempdata = getTemperatureData()
    return render_template('getjson.html', **locals())
```

This passes it the local variable tempdata. After this, I made a html file (getjson.html) with the simple code of:

```
{{tempdata}}
```

How ever when I load the webpage and check in the inspect element tab I get this which looks like pythonanywhere or flask has added all this html data as such:

```
<html>
    #shadow-root (open)
    <head></head>
    <body>{"temperature": 11.0, "datetime": "12-12-12 23-23-23"}</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that my google charts graph won't load and it seems to be receiving this data in the network preview tab in my browser, which looks completely modified from what I want it to receive (which it should be a json object) but it has all these added characters:

```
{&#34;temperature&#34;: 11.0, &#34;datetime&#34;: &#34;12-12-12 23-23-23&#34;}
```

The code for my google chart which should be able to live update is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Date Time');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    var options = {
      title: 'Temperature Data',
      curveType: 'none',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    drawChart();
    setInterval(drawChart, 10000);

    function drawChart() {
      $.getJSON({
        url: 'removed from public view just in case',
        type: 'get'
      }).done(function (jsonData) {
        data.addRows([
          [jsonData.datetime, jsonData.temperature]
        ]);
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
      });
    }
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Somebody suggested changing it as follows, which inserts the received data into an element and returns the value of it, but that doesn't work.

```
 function decodeEntities(encodedString) {
        var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
        textArea.innerHTML = encodedString;
        return textArea.value;
    }

    function drawChart() {
        $.getJSON({
            url: 'removed ...',
            type: 'get'
        }).done(function (jsonData) {
            jsonData = decodeEntities(jsonData);
            data.addRows([
            [jsonData.datetime, jsonData.temperature]
            ]);
            chart.draw(data, options);
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            });
    }
```

Really looking for a working solution to this problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your flask endpoint should not return this

```
return render_template('getjson.html', **locals())
```

which will return html. Instead do something like this:

```
from flask import jsonify
return jsonify(your_data)
```